# v4l2loopback doesn't create the /dev/video/ files

Tags: linux-mint, v4l2loopback

im trying to make v4l2loopback work on my desktop PC (no hardware camera) with mint 19.3, kernel 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64.

I followed the [official instructions](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) and compiled from git the v4l2loopback module and everything seem to run correctly, as no error prompted  while running the instructions, but when i do `ll /dev/v*` there's no /dev/videoN entry.
I also tried with the flags exclusive_caps=1 and devices=2 but to no avail.

Any idea what i might be missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you need to load the module (e.g. using `modprobe`) before you can use it.

see also https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback#run